# What does epsilon do when used in a bisection search algorithm?

Tags: python, binary, binary-search-tree, bisection

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
ans = 0.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon and ans <= x:
    ans += 0.00001
    numGuesses += 1
print 'numGuesses =', numGuesses
if abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print 'Failed on square root of', x
else:
    print ans, 'is close to square root of', x
```

Comment: Dear @Seth Garrett please clarify your question & goal

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure that it is Python question and not just math.

Epsilon is a tolerance that you give. Otherwise your number can be very very small but still not zero which is actually numerical noise
basically mathematically correct to compare the difference with some tolerance rather with number directly eg value**2==x due to above mentioned reason